# How to create a javascript function that output a list of object with a list of the object's property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a piece of javascript that looks like the following

```
var set = [{
  name: 'a',
  property1: '',
  property2: '',
},
{
  name: 'b',
  property1: '',
  property2: '',
},
{
  name: 'c',
  property1: '',
  property2: '',
}];
```

Since `property1` and `property2` are both empty for all objects, I want to automate this such that I only need to keep track of the name. Something like:

```
namelist = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
magicFunction(namelist);
```

that `magicFunction` can return that `set` I mentioned above. I am very new to javascript, if you think this is too rudimentary for stackoverflow, please give me a few keywords so I know what I should be searching for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

To get `set` from `nameList`

```
var namelist = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var set = namelist.map(function(e) { return { name: e, property1: 0, property2: 0 }});
```

```js
function magicFunction(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(e) {
    return {
      name: e,
      property1: 0,
      property2: 0
    }
  });
}

var namelist = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
set = magicFunction(namelist);

console.log(set);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(set, 0, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: where is `property1` and `property2`?

Comment: @return0 You want to remove it, `I want to automate this such that I only need to keep track of the name. Something like:

namelist = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
magicFunction(namelist);`

Comment: oh, I meant that `magicFunction` will take in this `namelist` and output that giant dictionary array (set)...

Comment: @sheriffderek No, OP just want a function to transform array to required array of object. Please check the code snippet

Comment: `.map` function is a magicFunction in this case. It returns what OP want.

Comment: @Tushar I don't think name should be a string like `"name"`, but actually just `name`. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @return0 `name` is **string** here, so the quotes, and No, there is no way to change that

Comment: @Tushar—well, property names can be [*symbols*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-symbol-value)… but not here, no. Or yes (not here). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function magicFunction(nameList){
var set = [];


for(var i = 0; i<nameList.length;i++){
  var temp = new Object();
  temp.property1='';
  temp.property2='';
  temp.name=nameList[i];
  set.push(temp);  
}
  return set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to use a constructor function and then 'construct' or return objects from that and store in your set:

```
// quick array
var someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
// define array for output
var set = [];
// constructor to create the objects
function something(name, param1, param2) {
    this.name = name;
    this.property1 = param1;
    this.property2 = param2;
}
// run through the quick array and build the objects with the constructor - push into 'set'
var magicFunction = function(arrayName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
    set.push( new something( someArray[i] ) );
  }
}

magicFunction(someArray);

console.log(set);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/c5j86qy6/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

```js
/* instead of console.log */
function log(val){
    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify( val , null , ' ') + '</pre>');
};


function magicFunction( listOfNames ) {
  return listOfNames.map(function( currentValue ){
    return {
      name       : currentValue ,
      property1  : '',
      property2  : '',
    };
  })
};

var namelist = ['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f'];
log( magicFunction(namelist) );
```